# Delete metadata in multiple files

Tags: notepad++, html, find-and-replace, metadata

How do i use Find and Replace in Files in Notepad++ to delete the following lines from multiple files?

```
<meta name="perc_linkback" id="perc_linkback" content="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

and

```
<link rel="canonical" href="xxxxxxxxxxx.html"/>
```

Where xxxxxxxxxxx is a string of different characters that varies in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following regex string : `<meta name="perc_linkback" id="perc_linkback" content=".*"/>` to select `<meta name="perc_linkback" id="perc_linkback" content="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>` And select Regular Expression radio button

[image]

Thing to notice is whenever you need to select a variable number of characters use `.*` And when you need to select `.` use `\.`

So to select `<link rel="canonical" href="xxxxxxxxxxx\.html"/>` search string should be `<link rel="canonical" href=".*.html"/>`